# Abrir archivo CSV con PHP y CodeIgniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, csv, importación

necesito ayuda de como abrir un archivo CSV con CodeIgniter, lo que debo hacer es, abrir el archivo y poder recorrerlo para agregar el contenido en la base de datos, me he llevado ya dos semanas buscando información, viendo videos y todo eso, pero aun así no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, he probado códigos que no me han arrojado resultados, el último código que utilicé es el siguiente, se los dejo acá, y se los voy explicando mas menos.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Excel_import extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('excel_import_model');
    $this->load->library('excel');
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('admin_excel_import'); 
}

function fetch()
{
    $data = $this->excel_import_model->select();
    $output = '
    <h3 align="center">Total Data - '.$data->num_rows().'</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Emails</th>
                <th>Mesas</th>
                <th>Descuento Propio</th>
                <th>Ventas Sin Stock</th>
                <th>Activo</th>
                <th>Created at</th>
                <th>Updated at</th>

            </tr>
    ';
    foreach($data->result() as $row)
    {
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->nombre.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->direccion.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->telefono.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->emails.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->mesas.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->descuento_propio.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->venta_sin_stock.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->activo.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->created_at.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->updated_at.'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    echo $output;
}


function import()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
        $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];


        $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
        foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
        {
            $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
            for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
            {
                $nombre = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
                $direccion = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $telefono = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $emails = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $mesas = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue();
                $descuento_propio = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue();
                $ventas_sin_stock = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue();
                $activo = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();
                $created_at = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();
                $updated_at = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue();
                $data[] = array(
                    'nombre'                =>  $nombre,
                    'rut'                   =>  $rut,
                    'descuento'             =>  $descuento,
                    'porcentaje_descuento'  =>  $porcentaje_descuento,
                    'fiado'                 =>  $fiado,
                    'codigo'                =>  $codigo,
                    'activo'                =>  $activo,
                    'created_at'            =>  $created_at,
                    'updated_at'            =>  $updated_at,
                );
            }
        }

        $this->excel_import_model->insert($data);
        echo 'Importación Realizada con Éxito';
    }   
}
}
?>
```

Este código es el Controller, el **index** me lleva a la vista para poder cargar el archivo csv. La función **fetch** me muestra mediante ajax el contenido de la tabla en la base de datos actual. La función **import** me carga lo sustraído del archivo csv, lo toma y lo copia en la base de datos actual.

```
<?php
class Excel_import_model extends CI_Model
{
function select()                       
{
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('sucursal');
    return $query;
}

function insert($data)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('sucursal', $data);
}
}
```

Este código es el modelo. La función **select**, envía el contenido de la tabla *sucursal* en una consulta de bd.
Y la función **insert** inserta el contenido de *$data* en la base de datos actual.

Y este esta es la vista:

```
<body>
    <h2 align="center">Migrate Table</h2>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <br /><br />
        <!--<h3 align="center">Migrate Table Clientes</h3> -->
        <form method="post" id="import_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p><label>Select Excel File</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required accept=".csv" /></p> <!-- archivos soportados para la carga-->
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="import" value="Cargar" class="btn btn-info" />   <!-- botón para subir archivo -->
        </form>
        <br />
        <div class="table-responsive" id="customer_data">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    load_data();

    function load_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>excel_import/fetch",
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data){
                $('#customer_data').html(data);
            }
        })
    }

    $('#import_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>excel_import/import",
            method:"POST",
            data:new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data){
                $('#file').val('');
                load_data();
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    });

});
</script>
```

la función **load_data()** me carga el contenido de la base de datos actual usando ajax. Y la función **excel_import/import** debería de importarme los datos del csv a la base de datos, y actualizarla para al momento de cargarlos verlos en pantalla. Pero a la única parte que llego es al cargar el csv, y ni el botón de cargar me funciona.
PORFAVOR ALGUNA AYUDA!! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un script con php puro, para realizar la lectura y carga de datos de un CSV a MySQL, solo pon este código en tu `controller` y llámalo desde ajax, pasando el archivo CSV, esta comentado el código así que no deberías de tener problemas para poder ejecutarlo, es importante que verifiques que esta separado por comas.

```
$fname =$_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];

            $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

            if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
            {
                 //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
                $filename = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];
                $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {

                        //Insertamos los datos con los valores...
                        $datosController = array("val0" => $data[0], "val1" => $data[1], "val2" => $data[2], "val3" => $data[3], "val4" => $data[4], "val5" => $data[5], "val6" => $data[6]);

                        //Aqui llamas a tu modelo para realizar el insert
                        $respuesta = $conexion->insertDatos($datosController);


                }
                 //cerramos la lectura del archivo "abrir archivo" con un "cerrar archivo"
                fclose($handle);

                echo "Archivo cargado correctamente";
            }
            else
            {
                //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive cuando es cvs, revisarlo para ver si esta separado por " , "
            echo "Error al cargar el archivo";
            }

        }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Pero ahora estoy mas enfocado  en no aplicar AJAX y realizar directamente lo que me piden, que es poder abrir este CSV y traspar su contenido a una base de datos usando PHP y CI. Abría una forma de adaptar esto y por ejemplo, al momento de hacer click en "Cargar" el archivo, llegar al código que me envíaste. Y otra consulta, ya que no lo tengo separado por comas el csv, en esta línea de código...

> fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))

Al final, en vez de la ",", reemplazando por un ";" sería posible leerlo así el csv separado por comas o no?. Saludos

Comment: Debería funcionar, el segundo parámetro es la longitud y el siguiente el delimitador.